# XCode Pan resets image to center when changes are made to the scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, pan

I have a UIScrollView with 2 images inside of it. I have pan, pinch, and rotate gestures hooked up to the scrollview and everything works fine. However when I tap a button that performs an action on the scroll view, the pan will reset to its center. The pinch to zoom and rotate do not reset their values but the pan does. How can I code it to not reset to center but still not fly off the screen when touched?

Here is my code for the pan gesture:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer { 

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                 recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying that the view controlled by the pan resets to the center of the scrollview?

Comment: Yes it goes back to it's origin point whenever a change is made to the scrollview. For example a button press changes an imageview within the scrollview and the pan will reset back to the origin.

Comment: @Zigglzworth I tried it with a regular old uiimageview, the pan will always reset back to it's original center point (the object will move and stay moved but if I have external code changing something with the object the object will go back to it's original center point and I just want it to stay where it was moved to)

Comment: Most likely due to auto layout. If you didn't turn off auto layout, then it's on, and you shouldn't set any frames when using auto layout -- if you do, the view moves back to the position defined by its constraints whenever any action causes the view to be redrawn.

Comment: I have auto layout turned off